# Best practice to organize a 200+ tables import project

Tags: ssis, project-organization, ssis-data-flow

This question is going to be a purely organizational question about SSIS project best practice for medium sized imports.

So I have source database which is continuously being enriched with new data. Then I have a staging database in which I sometimes load the data from the source database so I can work on a copy of the source database and migrate the current system. I am actually using a SSIS Visual Studio project to import this data.

My issue is that I realised the actual design of my project is not really optimal and now I would like to move this project to SQL Server so I can schedule the import instead of running manually the Visual Studio project. That means the actual project needs to be cleaned and optimized.

So basically, for each table, the process is simple: truncate table, extract from source and load into destination. And I have about 200 tables. Extractions cannot be parallelized as the source database only accepts one connection at a time. So how would you design such a project?

I read from Microsoft documentation that they recommend to use one Data Flow per package, but managing 200 different package seems quite impossible, especially that I will have to chain for scheduling import. On the other hand a single package with 200 Data Flows seems unamangeable too...

---

Edit 21/11:

The first apporach I wanted to use when starting this project was to extract my table automatically by iterating on a list of table names. This could have worked out well if my source and destination tables had all the same schema object names, but the source and destination database being from different vendor (BTrieve and Oracle) they also have different naming restrictions. For example BTrieve does not reserve names and allow more than 30 characters names, which Oracle does not. So that is how I ended up manually creating 200 data flows with a semi-automatic column mapping (most were automatic).

When generating the CREATE TABLE query for the destination database, I created a reusable C# library containing the methods to generate the new schema object names, just in case the methodology could automated. If there was any custom tool to generate the package that could use an external .NET library, then this might do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked into [BIDS Helper](http://bidshelper.codeplex.com/)'s BIML (Business Intelligence Markup Language) as a package generation tool? I've used it to create multiple packages that all follow the same basic truncate-extract-load pattern. If you need slightly more cleverness than what's built into BIML, there's [BimlScript](http://bimlscript.com/GetStarted/AboutBimlScript), which adds the ability to embed C# code into the processing.

From your problem description, I believe you'd be able to write one BIML file and have that generate two hundred individual packages. You could probably use it to generate one package with two hundred data flow tasks, but I've never tried pushing SSIS that hard.

Comment: Thank you for this, I will have a close look. I updated my original question so it matches the scenario you describe.

Answer (score 0):

You can basically create 10 child packages each having 20 data flow tasks and create a master package which triggers these child pkgs.Using [parent to child configuration](http://www.bidn.com/blogs/mikedavis/ssis/155/passing-variable-values-from-parent-package-to-child-ssis) create a single [XML file](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/xml-configuration-files-in-sql-server-integration-services/) configuration file .Define the precedence constraint for executing the package in serial fashion in master pkg. In this way maintainability will be better compared to having 200 packages or single package with 200 data flow tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Following link may be useful to you.

[Single SSIS Package for Staging Process](http://sqlserverselect.blogspot.in/2011/03/single-ssis-package-staging-process.html)

Hope this helps!

Comment: That is actually the first approach I wanted to use when developing this project so everything would be automatic. But the issue is that my source (BTrive) and staging(Oracle) have very different schema object naming conventions, therefore an automatic mapping of column names was not possible (for example "Time" in the source DB became "TIME_" in my destination DB, as "TIME" is a reserved word in Oracle). Therefore, all those data flow had to be manually configured.